# K means clustering analysis to define geological facies using 2 attributes (ERT & seismic)

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, k-means

dear all.

Currently I am doing a project where the goal is to define geological facies of an area by using ML. The method that we are doing is k-means  (we have no labels beforehand) and we are using 2 attributes: ERT and Seismic (both in log). However I am having difficulty  in analysis of the clusters. What can be the best way to analyze clusters? How can I look the values of ERT and seismic data that is included in each cluster?

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: You should have cluster assignments for each point. You can use them to do what analyses you want to perform.